# Не могу вывести UTF символ используя вывод в ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, c, консоль, ncurses

Данный кусок кода рисует змейку по координатам, используя функцию mvprintw. Не могу разобраться как вывести на экран символ - ߜ. Вот код программы:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    x = c[i].X;
    y = c[i].Y;
    unsigned wchar_t head;
    switch(d)
    {
    case UP: head = 'A'; break;


    case DOWN: head = L'ߜ'; break; //ߜ
    // Вот этот символ ^


    case LEFT: head = '<'; break;
    case RIGHT: head = '>'; break;
    default: break;
    }
    mvprintw(food.Y, food.X, "%lc", '$');
    //mvprintw(i, 0, "%d %d\n",y,x);
    mvprintw(y, x, "%c", (i) ? '@' : head);
}
```

Comment: что у вас выводит вместо нужного символа?

Comment: вместо нужного символа выводится "~\"

Comment: @SemyonLabzov  При сборке Вы используете библиотеку `ncurses` или `ncursesw` ?

Comment: @Yaroslav Да, я использовал ncursesw

Comment: А с locale у вас все в порядке? Т.е. правильный setlocale в программе сделан и без curses в терминал все выводится правильно?

Comment: @avp, locale я выставил следующим образом - setlocale(LC_ALL, ""). А если вывести через printf("%lc", 'ߜ'); то компилятор выводит предупреждение. 
 warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  printf("%lc", 'ߜ');

Comment: Ну, так писать нельзя. Нужно выводить `wprintf(L"%lc, L'ߜ');` К сожалению код в комментариях не понабиваешь, придется общаться в "ответе". Сейчас набью тестик, а вы попробуйте.

Comment: А вы пробовали добавлять строку c setlocale(LC_ALL, "") до первого вызова функции initscr() библиотеки ncurses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте, работает у вас или нет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  if (av[1])
    puts(loc);
  wchar_t wc = L'я';
  wprintf(L"-- %lc --\n", wc);  // wc = 'ߜ'
  wc = L'ߜ';
  wprintf(L"-- %lc --\n", wc);  // 'ߜ'

}
```

У меня

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc --version
gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc twc.c && ./a.out
-- я --
-- ߜ --
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out hashsj
en_US.UTF-8
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Обратите внимание, что обычный вывод (puts/printf и т.п.) **несовместим** с выводом wide символов (wprintf и т.п.).

Возможно у вас где-то тестовая печать до вывода wchar_t и поэтому ничего не отображается.

Comment: Не могу изменить код, компилятор выводит ошибку: "error: cannot convert ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int mvprintw(int, int, const char*, ...)’
         mvprintw(y, x, L"%lc", (i) ? '@' : head);"

Comment: @SemyonLabzov, мой код у вас компилируется и выполняется?

Comment: Да он выполняется правильно

Comment: А в ncurses есть аналог wprintf?

Comment: @SemyonLabzov, у меня нет под рукой ncursesw, так что работающий пример с ней не сделаю. Попробуйте что-то минимально простое с теми же символами, что и в консольной программе и вашим  `mvprintw()`. Учтите, что по виду сообщения об ошибке похоже вам надо написать `mvprintw(y, x, "%lc", (i) ? '@' : head);` (т.е. строку форматов без `L` а также вероятно `L'@'` вместо просто `'@'`)

Comment: Так, программа выводит "~\" вместо нужного символа

Comment: @SemyonLabzov, т.е. на самом деле выводит, что и раньше (в комментарии к своему вопросу вы эту строку упоминали). Попрбуйте что-то простое -- русскую букву, например, `б` (интересно, а эта либа вообще-то работает? т.е. с ней какие-нибудь examples есть?) И еще, вы конкретный код, который выводит `~\\` приведите (например, в дополнении к вопросу)

Comment: Походу нормально выводятся только символы из ascii (Вместо "б" какой-то китайский символ). Видимо в ncurses нужно искать другую функцию

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57140/discussion-between-avp-and-semyon-labzov).

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание :

```
mvprintw(y, x, "%c", (i) ? '@' : head);
```

Вы пытаетесь переменную типа *wchar_t* вывести по символу форматирования %c. В руководстве по *printf* написано:

> %c      If no l modifier is present, the int argument is converted to
>   an unsigned  char, and the resulting character is written.  If an l
>   modifier is present, the wint_t (wide character) argument is converted
>   to a multibyte sequence by a call to  the wcrtomb(3)  function, with a
>   conversion state starting in the initial state, and the resulting
>   multibyte string is written.

Т.е., попробуйте использовать %lc.

Comment: Нет, резултат не изменился - вместо нужного символа выводится "~\"

Comment: Несмотря на то, что в доке(!!!) написано: *При использовании современного компилятора, поддерживаюшего добавленные в 1995 году средства работы с двухбайтовыми символами, можно к спецификации с применить модификатор l, чтобы указать на использование двухбайтовых символов. Модификатор 1 можно также использовать с командой формата s для вывода строки двухбайтовых символов* - не работает!!! Почему - не знаю... Может надо компилировать с  какими-то особыми ключами...

Comment: Попробуйте заменить 'ߜ' на L'ߜ'

Comment: @int3, Не работает, вместо нужного символа вообще ничего не выводится